# How to iterate and format rows in a dataframe using a separate file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm looking for some help in how to format some rows using Python dataframe. Essentially I have two files where the contents of 1 influences the other file. So in my example I have

File 1 and File 2

```
Currency,Shifts.   NewCurrency,Value
EUR,1              EUR,0.5
USD,1.5            USD,1.5
ZAR,2              ZAR,10
```

The idea is I should loop through file 2 and when I find the corresponding currency, I multiple column 2 by the shift in File 1 and produce a single result file with results as follows

```
NewCurrency,Value
EUR,0.5
USD,2.25
ZAR,20
```

This is the code I'm using

```
  for i, row in df.iterrows():
        newFX = float(row['SpotPriceVAL']) * float(multiplier)
        df.at[i, 'SpotPriceVAL'] = newFX

    scenario_file = 'fx.csv'
    print (df.to_csv(scenario_file ,index=None, sep=',', mode='w'))
```

The problem is, although the shift multiplier works, because all the output is to the same file the USD and EUR values are been overwritten so I am only getting the last entry processed. I'm just not sure how to handle this situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
In [1664]: df1                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1664]: 
  Currency  Shifts
0      EUR     1.0
1      USD     1.5
2      ZAR     2.0

In [1665]: df2                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1665]: 
  Currency  Shifts
0      EUR     0.5
1      USD     1.5
2      ZAR    10.0

In [1657]: p = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Currency')                                                                                                                                                            

In [1658]: p['Shifts'] = p.Shifts_x * p.Shifts_y

In [1662]: p.drop(['Shifts_x', 'Shifts_y'], 1, inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                

In [1663]: p                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[1663]: 
  Currency  Shifts
0      EUR    0.50
1      USD    2.25
2      ZAR   20.00
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Just testing this now but I can see one problem and it's my fault. The column names will not be the same and the number of columns will differ between the files. Will the 'on' still be used here?

Comment: `on` basically represents the common column across dataframes to join them on. So, that will be the same.

Comment: In the end I had to use a different solution as I couldn't get that one to work for me. See below.

Answer (score 0):

This was the end solution to fixing this issue

```
    try:
        for index, row in df_scen.iterrows():
            message = " Processing currency %s with shock %s and %s" % (row[0], row[2], scenario)
            print (logtime + " " + 'INFO: [' + scriptname + ']' + message)
            spot = df.loc[df["IDENTIFIER"] == row[0]]["SpotPriceVAL"].tolist()[0]
            newFX = float(spot) * float(row[2])
            df.loc[(df.IDENTIFIER == row[0]),'SpotPriceVAL']=newFX
            df.to_csv(scenario_file, index=None, sep=',', mode='w')
    except IndexError as error:
        print ("Currency %s does not exist in File" % row[0])
```